Cordova-ios cookies issue
I am developing a Cordova iOS app with React.js and recently switched from using
file:// to a custom scheme app://localhost by setting the following preferences in config.xml:
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />

This change allows the app to be served from app://localhost instead of file://. However, after making this change, cookies no longer seem to be stored or sent in iOS. I use the js-cookie library to manage cookies
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

Cookies.set('test', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
console.log(Cookies.get('test'));

I use the latest version of cordova and cordova-ios
"cordova": "12.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "7.1.1",

Are there specific configurations or known workarounds to enable cookie storage and retrieval when using custom schemes in Cordova apps on iOS?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

I imagine there’s a reason you’re using cookies, but I had the exact same problem... literally the same, and to avoid getting stuck, I ended up using sessionStorage, which worked perfectly.
I also tried to fix it by checking if there was any Cordova plugin to solve this, as I was testing and noticed that no cookies were being stored when I looked in my Safari Technology Preview...
So, I went with using sessionStorage. If, for some reason, you really need to use cookies, I hope a solution comes up soon...
